# Invalid Response Format Posting to ASMX from jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asmx

"Error 500: Invalid Response format"

I looked around stack overflow, and found a few solutions but none applied to me.

So I've got a webservice, http://Komputerz4Kidz.com/mailer/Service1.asmx/SendMail is the URL. It is an exact replica, save for the namespace and a variable or two, of a script I threw together to send mail via jQuery using POST.

The example works on another site and is hosted from the same server. It's got it's own application pool in IIS, and that is setup properly to .NET 4.0 integrated.

It's very simple, not a lot going on here:

```
function ContactSubmit() {
var Name = $('input:text[name=pickup_name]').val();
var Email = $('input:text[name=pickup_email]').val();
var Message = $('textarea[name=pickup_message]').val();
var PickupDate = $('input:text[name=pickup_date]').val();
$.ajax({

type: "POST",
url: "http://Komputerz4Kidz.com/mailer/Service1.asmx/SendMail",
data: {
_name: Name,
_email: Email,
_message: Message,
p_date: PickupDate},

success: ContactSuccess,

error: function (x, y, z) {console.log(x);console.log(y);console.log(z);alert('ERROR');}
```

WEB SERVICE WORKS FINE FROM SERVER AND FUNCTIONS 100% when from the server I run:

komputerz4kidz.com/mailer/service1.asmx?op=SendMail

**Live example: www.Komputerz4Kidz.com contact form bottom left of page**

Thanks!

Comment: You may fix this with routing, but you have different URLs server1.asmx?op=SendMail and service1.asmx/SendMail are you really running the code you think you are?

Comment: I tried visiting Komputerz4Kidz.com, but I get a 404 error when I click on the Contacts link.

Comment: The site is still in development. However, I have a working example on my site, JamesRobertCook.com that uses almost identical code save for variables. The mailers are two different projects in Visual Studio, and are in the respective directories on the server side.

Any ideas?

Comment: Also: server1.asmx?op=SendMail is how I can hit the web service manually from the server. You won't ever be able to hit that. 

It works from the server, only from the server using that url. Which is why I'm trying to post from jQuery to the web service ;)